# AppleScript with iTunes on a remote machine

Tags: cocoa, applescript, itunes

I have a Cocoa-AppleScript project in XCode where I'm trying to send some commands to iTunes on a local network computer. For some reason this works:

```
tell application "iTunes" of machine "eppc://user:pass@computer.local"
    playpause
end tell
```

But this does not:

```
set remoteMachine to "eppc://user:pass@computer.local"
tell application "iTunes" of machine remoteMachine
    playpause
end tell
```

I get the error "Can't find remote machine." Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured it out, or at least one way to do it. You can specify the application itself on the remote machine, like:

```
set theRemoteApp to application "eppc://user:pass@computer.local/iTunes"
using terms from application "iTunes"
    tell theRemoteApp
        playpause
    end tell
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `named` qualifier:

```
set remoteMachine to "eppc://user:pass@computer.local"
tell application "iTunes" of machine named remoteMachine
    playpause
end tell
```